# How can I write a review?

Tags: academic-writing

Recently, I am working on writing a review about a book and I wanted to know how I can check my grammer mistakes. In other words: how can I write a paragraph or essay in a right way without any grammar or spelling mistakes?
And if there are any resources I can learn from, please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I am glad that you like my answer, but as you are pretty new here is a little tip: it's encouraged to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer to give people around the globe time to have a look at your question and the answers, so that potential problems can be discussed. Some people may be discouraged from interacting with your question if they think you have already found your solution. Of course it's completely up to you whether you want to accept something and if so when and what. You can change it as often as you like. Just a little tip for the future.

Comment: @Secespitus  I didnt know that before .. thanks for the tip

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about learning grammar, not about writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't be one hundred percent sure that you don't have any mistakes in your writing. It's the same as with testing a program - you can find bugs and be certain that a version therefore has flaws, but there will almost always be things you just can't test, because you don't have the time to fully check every little detail in a project of a significant size.

There are many tools that can help you, such as the basic spellcheckers that programs like Microsoft Word have already included. They will be able to pick up a lot of common mistakes and make you aware of them. But there will always be edge cases where these spellcheckers are simply wrong. See [Knowing when to disobey the advice of grammar software](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/33326/23159) for more information about this topic.

You can also give your draft to someone that regularly checks writing for mistakes. Professional editors can help you a lot. See [Where do I go looking for an editor?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/32157/23159) and [How do I find an affordable editor?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/2529/23159) for more information.

You can also write something and then let it sit for a couple of days or weeks while working on something different. You will more easily pick up the problems in your writing if you are not so close to your writing anymore, because you are routine-blinded when reading the same thing over and over. See for example [this answer to *So I finished my novel. Now what do I do?*](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/3993/23159) for more information. This advice works better if it's a longer project that you are working on where you can simply *take a few days off*.

For a general tips collection on making *fewer* mistakes (as opposed to *none* that you are aiming for) you might want to look at [How can I catch more errors when I proofread?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/5400/23159)

Comment: Stellar answer. Writing something without mistakes is an unrealistic dream.

Comment: It's actually *fewer* mistakes. And I apologize. I'm not trying to be a critic, but I just couldn't pass up commenting on the irony. :)

I should also add that even professional editors will make mistakes. Hopefully not as many as people who don't do it for a living, but nothing that's been published has been completely free of some kind of error.